# row lock sql server

Tags: sql-server, locking, row

I have to take a lock on one row in a table for read/update.
I have written below code but its taking too much time.
Please suggest any other method.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
DECLARE @v_id_counter NUMERIC;  
DECLARE @v_new_rows NUMERIC;
SET @v_new_rows = 10;   

        SELECT @v_id_counter = id 
        FROM tbl_keys [UPDLOCK  ROWLOCK] with (Xlock) 
        WHERE name='tbl_docs'

        update tbl_keys set id = (@v_id_counter + @v_new_rows ) where name='tbl_docs'        
COMMIT;
```

`tbl_keys`: It stores the primary keys for many tables & its alternative for sequence

`tbl_docs`: It is the table where I have to insert N rows

Answer (score 1):

Why read the value before the update? Just use the value in the update, and you don't need a transaction at all:

```
DECLARE @v_new_rows NUMERIC;
SET @v_new_rows = 10;   

update tbl_keys set id = id + @v_new_rows where name='tbl_docs'
```

Comment: the value is an output parameter